# Can I use insertAdjacentHTML to insert DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

`insertAdjacentHTML` expects 2 arguments:

- position (`"beforebegin"`, `"afterbegin"`, `"beforeend"`, `"afterend"`)
- html (will be converted from text to DOM)

Can I pass DOM element as the second argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.insertAdjacentHTML()` only accept string that will be parsed as HTML and inserted (like `innerHTML`)

To insert DOM element you can use `.insertAdjacentElement()`

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

Comment: Why is the best answer all the way down here?

Answer (score 19):

While you can't pass a DOM element directly, **it's possible to pass `element.outerHTML`** to feed `insertAdjacentHTML`'s second parameter with it's HTML string representation.

Example:

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const child = document.createElement('p');

child.innerHTML = 'Awesome!';
parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', child.outerHTML);

// <div class="parent">
//   <p>Awesome!</p>
// </div>
```

Answer (score 17):

For [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), the documentation clearly states that the first argument *must* be of type string

> `element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);`
>
> `position` is the position relative to the element, and must be one of
>   the following ***strings***:
>   *"beforebegin", "afterbegin", "beforeend", "afterend"*

It's not very clear about what the second argument can be, but testing shows that `toString()` is executed internally on the second argument, so the answer is

**yes**, you can in most cases pass a DOM element as the second argument, but the real answer is **no**, it won't be appended to the page, instead you'll just get the string

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

as the DOM element is converted to a string, and that means the function always expects the second argument to be a valid ***string*** of HTML, not a DOM element.

Here's a quick test

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById('one'); 

var d3 = document.createElement('div');
d3.innerHTML = 'three';

d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');

d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', d3);
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
```

There are other methods available that are much more suitable for actual DOM elements, for instance `appendChild`, `insertBefore` etc.

Which one to use depends on where the element is to be inserted etc, but inserting in the same place as the four options available in `insertAdjacentHTML` is possible, and generally not very hard to do.

There's also [`Element.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) which works exactly like `insertAdjacentHTML`, but accepts a DOM node instead of a string of HTML.

Comment: Thank you for answer but my question is about the second argument.